# Why this JSON.stringify() return undefined?

Tags: javascript, json

This snippet is from MDN and I wonder why it return undefined.

```
JSON.stringify({ [Symbol.for('foo')]: 'foo' }, function(k, v) {
  if (typeof k === 'symbol') {
    return 'a symbol';
  }
});
```

The comment on MDN shows it should return '{}' instead of `undefined`.
I ran the code in node.js.

Comment: You need to return for the main, outer object too. Right now you're returning `undefined` for that, so that's the result. The key will be an empty string in that case. `if (k === "") return v`

Comment: Which version of node.js? How did you run it, did you paste it in the console or ran it as a script?

Comment: If you link the MDN page that uses this example we can fix it (it's a wiki!)